# JOOQ Plugin in Maven pom.xml file

Tags: spring, maven, jooq

I'm trying to build the example given on the official JOOQ git repo [here](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-example). The maven `pom.xml` file contains the following plugin for JOOQ:

```html
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <version>${org.jooq.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <jdbc>
                    <driver>${db.driver}</driver>
                    <url>${db.url}</url>
                    <user>${db.username}</user>
                    <password>${db.password}</password>
                </jdbc>
                <generator>
                    <target>
                        <packageName>com.learnd.jooq.db</packageName>
                        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                    </target>
                </generator>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However I'm not managing to `mvn compile`, the project, and I'm getting the following output because of the`${org.jooq.version}` variable in the `<version>` tag. But whenever I've seen this plugin inserted, I've seen it done this way, even [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jooq-with-spring).

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.jooq:jooq-spring-example:jar:3.10.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ org.jooq:jooq-spring-example:${org.jooq.version}, /home/lukec/Desktop/jOOQ-spring-example/pom.xml, line 8, column 14
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jOOQ Spring Example 3.10.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:jar:3.10.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.213 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-18T03:47:16+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/150M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.10.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:jar:3.10.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Can anyone help me with this? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Its most likely because Maven cant find the jOOQ-codegen-maven 3.10.0-SNAPSHOT version in your local .m2. I checked the link from your question and I see the spring project and its dependent project jOOQ-codegen-maven in this link, https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-codegen-maven/pom.xml, so import this and build it, so that this version gets into your local .m2. And I see jOOQ-codegen-maven project has a parent jooq-parent, so you will probably need to build that as well for the dependencies to get resolved.

Once you have built and run jOOQ-codegen-maven and jooq-parent successfully, your local .m2 should have these dependencies, try building jooq-spring-example again and now the 3.10.0-SNAPSHOT dependencies should be resolved properly.

The above should most likely fix the issue but in case if it doesn't work, you could possibly try using the version from central, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jooq/jooq-codegen-maven/3.9.5 and see if that helps build your spring example.

Answer (score 0):

There's no official release of 3.10.x jooq-codegen-maven plugin.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jooq/jooq-codegen-maven

You should try using any one of them found in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the code gen 3.10.0-SNAPSHOT has yet to be released, along with the rest of the 3.10.0-SNAPSHOT.

If you need the functionality that has been developed and are comforatable using a library that has not been released yet,

`git clone https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ`

then run

```
mvn install
```

To build jooq 3.10.0-SNAPSHOT to your local repository. The example should run on your local machine. Beware that it will not work elsewhere (EX: jenkins machine).

If you do not feel comfortable using this unreleased code, use the latest published published published release version's example:

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/version-3.9.0-branch/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-example

As the dependency graph expects 3.10.0-SNAPSHOT.